# How should I add/redo this python script to input a value and print out a total for all?

Tags: python

I need to be able to input a value for each seat and have the script print out the total for all seats when the user enters 'q' to quit.  Here is the code so far:

```
cost = []
print 'Welcome to the receipt program!'
while True:
    cost = raw_input("Enter the value for the seat ['q' to quit]: ")
    if cost == 'q':
        break
print '*****'
print 'Total: $', cost
```

Comment: No it's not...I am working out of a book on my own trying to learn Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
totalCost = 0
print 'Welcome to the receipt program!'
while True:
    cost = raw_input("Enter the value for the seat ['q' to quit]: ")
    if cost == 'q':
        break
    else:
        totalCost += int(cost)

print '*****'
print 'Total: $', totalCost
```

Comment: Thank You....Now here's my other dilema....I changed the int to float because I wanted to use decimal places...now I need to validate what the input is...so if a user enters a string (like the word 'five' instead of the number) other than q or a number it tells them "I'm sorry, but 'five' isn't valid. please try again.....and then it prompts the user for the input again.  I am new to Python and have been wracking my brains on this simple problem.